# Is there a way to set the program counter on ARM without using the C ABI?

Tags: rust, ffi

This code works for setting the program counter to the address of the `vector_table` on the ARM architecture:

```
static mut JUMP: Option<extern "C" fn()> = None;
JUMP = Some(core::mem::transmute(vector_table));
(JUMP.unwrap())();
```

I calculate the vector table using `let vector_table = *((address + 4) as * const u32);`

*Is there any way of expressing the same in pure Rust code?*

The equivalent C code is:

```c
((void (*)(void))address[1])();
```

`address` is an `uint32_t *address`, so you offset it by 4 bytes to hit the vector table.

Comment: I don't understand why you consider use `extern "C"` as no pure Rust.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand but isn't extern C for declaring an FFI call to C? So I'm basically declaring an empty C function?  Which is the same as ((void (*)(void))? There is no way of expressing that in rust?

Comment: "There is no way of expressing that in rust?" you just did, `extern "C"` is a part of rust language, not C, I don't see the problem. You could "hide" these detail of implementation but that Rust code and as you said it's work as expected.

Comment: *isn't extern C for declaring an FFI call to C* — no, it's for declaring a function that uses the C ABI. You can use it [completely inside of a Rust program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45e2b6f7a4370d0c549682c5484e6e0e), although the usefulness there is limited.

Comment: *without using the C ABI* — **why**? What do you possibly hope to gain?

Comment: You can use assembly in rust: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.12.0/book/inline-assembly.html

Comment: I don't really want to gain anything it's more for exploration. I kind of want to do the JUMP call without having to do `unwrap` then call it as a function `()` if that makes sens. It's more about exploration than an actual problem or performance gain/size reduction. As suggested I guess one could do it with inline assembly but it's not really what I'm looking for. So what I possible hope to gain is some more knowledge of Rust ^^